# NodeJS: Check if an image only downloaded partway

Tags: node.js

I have created an image downloader in node.js. However when downloading images there is a chance the download will not complete, leaving me with a partially downloaded image ([looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrQwc.jpg)). This is the function I am using to download images:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra'); 
var progress = require('request-progress');
var probe = require('probe-image-size');
... 
downloadImage(url, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var req = request(url);
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirname)) fs.ensureDirSync(path.dirname(filename));
        var image;
        var bytes;
        var type;

        progress(req, { delay: 0 }).on('progress', function (state) {
            reportDownloadSpeed(status.speed);
        })
        .on('response', response => {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                type = mime.getExtension(response.headers['content-type']);
                filename = filename + '.' + type;
                image = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
                bytes = response.headers['content-length'];
                req.pipe(image);
            } else {
                reject(response.statusCode);
            }
        })
        .on('error', function (error) {
            reject(error);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            image.close();
            var input = require('fs').createReadStream(filename);
            // Get the width and height
            probe(input).then(result => {
                input.destroy();
                if (result != null) {
                    resolve({
                        'bytes': bytes,
                        'width': result.width,
                        'height': result.height,
                        'type': type
                    });
                } else {
                    reject('Not an image or corrupt');
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The partially downloaded images do not trigger any errors in this function.

Edit: Here is my updated code, it downloads the file but without the file extension:

```
function downloadImage(url, filenameWithoutExt) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var req = request(url);
        var response = null;
        var bytes;
        var dirname = path.dirname(filenameWithoutExt);
        var filename = filenameWithoutExt;
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirname)) fs.ensureDirSync(dirname);

        progress(req, { delay: 0 }).on('progress', function (state) {
            updateSpeed(state.speed);
        }).on('end', function () {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                var input = require('fs').createReadStream(filename);
                probe(input).then(result => {
                    input.destroy();
                    if (result != null) {
                        // return the image info
                        var highestQualityAvailable = true;
                        var resolution = {};
                        resolution.width = result.width;
                        resolution.height = result.height;
                        resolution.type = result.type;
                        resolve({
                            'bytes': bytes,
                            'resolution': resolution, // Resolution also includes the file extension as "type"
                            'highestQualityAvailable': highestQualityAvailable
                        });
                    } else {
                        reject({ 'name': 'DownloadedFileIsNotImageOrIsCorrupt', 'message': '^' });
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
            } else {
                reject({ 'name': 'StatusCodeError2', 'message': response.statusCode });
            }
        }).on('response', function (resp) {
            response = resp;
            filename = filename + '.' + mime.getExtension(response.headers['content-type']);
        }).on('error', function (resp) {
            reject(error);
        }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response event may be triggered prior to receiving all of the data. The `pipe` method can be used to write data to the destination stream as it becomes available, and should keep writing until there's no more. You can capture the status code and remove the file if the status is not 200 (otherwise it may contain an error response).

```
    ...
    let response = null;
    ...
    progress(request(url)
    ).on('progress', function(state){
        reportDownloadSpeed(state.speed); 
    }).on('end', function () { 
        if (response.statusCode != 200){
            console.log(`remove: ${filename}`);
            fs.unlinkSync(filename);
        }
    }).on('response', function(resp){
        response = resp;
    }).on('error', function(resp){
        reject(error);
    }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
```

Comment: Would my current code not do that though? It already throws and error whenever response is triggered and the statusCode is not 200.

Comment: yup, but in your code, `req.pipe(image);` is done in the 'response' event handling. The 'response' event may trigger this before the image is fully received. If you use the `progress` object's `pipe` function then it should continue adding to the file until it's fully received (it's kind of like a more succinct but equivalent to appending to the file on the 'data' event and closing the file on the 'end' event). This method would be similar to the example given in https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-progress

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I'd implement your example. I don't have the full filename until I can retrieve the file type from the response.

Comment: In that case, you can use the 'data' and 'end' events as described above

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. How would I implement this?

Comment: Sorry for one major necro, but I just got back to working on this and I still don't quite understand. There does not appear to be any documentation in npmjs.com/package/request-progress so I am unsure how to use the 'data' and 'end' events properly.