# Node JS/Gzip: Image file download ends prematurely with no error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a application in Node.js to download image files. However, I have been having an issue where if my download speed is slow or I lose connection the image I am downloading will be [truncated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7SoO.jpg). This would not be so bad if my program threw an error warning me that the image did not finish downloading, however, it does not and resolves as if the image downloaded successfully. I do not receive an error when I check the response code or probe the image after downloading.

This is the current code I am using to download images.

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const request = require('request');
var probe = require('probe-image-size');
var progress = require('request-progress');

var filename = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/myimage.jpg';
var req = request(createRequestHeaders('www.linktomyimage.com/image.jpg'));
downloadImage(req, filename)

function createRequestHeaders(url) {
    var cookie = `userid=${userid}; phash=${phash};`;
    return {
        'url': url,
        'method': 'GET',
        'gzip': true,
        'headers': {
            'Referer': `https://${website}/`,
            'Cookie': cookie
        }
    };
}

function downloadImage(req, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var response = null;
        var bytes;
        var dirname = path.dirname(filename);
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirname)) fs.ensureDirSync(dirname);

        progress(req, { delay: 0 }).on('progress', function (state) {
            updateDownloadSpeed(state.speed);
        }).on('end', function () {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                var input = require('fs').createReadStream(filename);
                probe(input).then(result => {
                    input.destroy();
                    if (result != null) {
                        resolve({bytes: bytes, width: result.width,
                                height: result.height,});
                    } else {
                        // The image size probe does not detect if the download was truncated
                        reject({ 'name': 'ImageMissingOrCorrupt');
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
            } else {
                // This is never triggered when the download stops and the image is truncated
                reject({ 'name': 'StatusCodeError', 'message': response.statusCode });
            }
        }).on('response', function (resp) {
            response = resp;
            bytes = response.headers['content-length'];
        }).on('error', function (error) {
            // This does not detect when an image is truncated either
            reject(error);
        }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
    });
}
```

I asked an earlier version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552680/nodejs-check-if-an-image-only-downloaded-partway) but after implementing suggestions from the answer my downloader still has the same issues. The code for my downloader has also changed since then.

How can I detect when an image has been truncated so I can instruct the downloader to reattempt the download it?

**Edit 1**

After reading [this](https://github.com/request/request/issues/1770) I think my issue might have something to do with the website I'm downloading from requiring me to use gzip and the client not being able to tell if the content has actually finished downloading when the server stops the response. However, I am not sure how to test for this happening.

**Edit 2**

This is what the response header looks like when my downloadedr successfully connects to an image.

```
cache-control:"public, max-age=31536000"
connection:"close"
content-disposition:"inline; filename=129.jpg"
content-length:"185756"
content-transfer-encoding:"binary"
content-type:"image/jpeg"
date:"Thu, 05 Sep 2019 00:15:11 GMT"
expires:"Fri, 04 Sep 2020 00:15:11 GMT"
server:"Apache"
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just check the size advertised v/s what you were able to download and determine if the file got truncated?

Comment: Try simply downloading the file without any fancy speed updater first. If it works, problem in the speed updater etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you trying to check that the `writeStream`'s [`bytesWritten`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_writestream_byteswritten) property equals to the `content-length` header you are receiving.

I have been playing around with your code and I have found that the `end` event for the request gets fired before the `writeStream` is closed, so I think there is actually no way for you to check this property at this point. Instead you should validate it on the `close` event of your `writeStream`.

Try this sample code and tell us how it goes:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const request = require('request');
var probe = require('probe-image-size');
var progress = require('request-progress');

var filename = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/myimage.jpg';
var writeSteam = fs.createWriteStream(filename)
var req = request(createRequestHeaders('www.linktomyimage.com/image.jpg'));
downloadImage(req, filename)

function createRequestHeaders(url) {
  var cookie = `userid=${userid}; phash=${phash};`;
  return {
    'url': url,
    'method': 'GET',
    'gzip': true,
    'headers': {
      'Referer': `https://${website}/`,
      'Cookie': cookie
    }
  };
}

function downloadImage(req, filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var response = null;
    var bytes;
    var dirname = path.dirname(filename);
    if (!fs.existsSync(dirname)) fs.ensureDirSync(dirname);

    // NEW CODE
    writeSteam.on('close', () => {
      if (bytes !== writeSteam.bytesWritten) { // NEW CODE
        // Here the write stream is closed, so we can compare the property bytesWritten with the bytes we expected to receive
        console.log('The size is not equal! Image is corrupt!')
        reject({ 'name': 'ImageCorrupt'})
      } else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        var input = require('fs').createReadStream(filename);
        probe(input).then(result => {
          input.destroy();
          if (result != null) {
            resolve({bytes: bytes, width: result.width,
              height: result.height,});
          } else {
            // The image size probe does not detect if the download was truncated
            reject({ 'name': 'ImageMissingOrCorrupt'});
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
      } else {
        // This is never triggered when the download stops and the image is truncated
        reject({ 'name': 'StatusCodeError', 'message': response.statusCode });
      }
    })

    progress(req, { delay: 0 }).on('progress', function (state) {
      updateDownloadSpeed(state.speed);
    }).on('end', function () {
      console.log('Ended request!!') // NEW CODE
    }).on('response', function (resp) {
      response = resp;
      bytes = response.headers['content-length'];
    }).on('error', function (error) {
      // This does not detect when an image is truncated either
      reject(error);
    }).pipe(writeSteam);
  });
}
```

Comment: I am currently testing this and will confirm this as the answer in a few days if it works.

Comment: After testing, I believe the code is successfully identifying when an image is not downloaded completely. However, I am having a separate issue when implementing this code.  For example, lets say I get an error in the `request.on('error')` event. The code should reject and my error should be handled where my function resolves. But even after rejecting this error, the `writeStream.on('close')` event is still triggered. I have tried adding a `return` after where I reject but the `writeStream.on('close')` event is still being triggered.

Comment: What about registering the `close` handler for the writable on the `end` handler of your readable? You could also use a flag but I dont think it is a good practise.

Comment: I have tried registering `close` inside the `end` event of my request. Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem. Marking as solved because indeed it does catch when my downloader fails to download the entire image.

Answer (score -1):

Using the data event I can track the amount of bytes I receive and check if it is equal to the bytes in the header when the end event is triggered.

```
var bytesRecieved = 0;
var bytes = -1;
...
bytes = response.headers['content-length'];
.on('response', function (resp) {
    bytes = response.headers['content-length']
}).on('data', function (chunk) {
    bytesRecieved += chunk.length;
}).on('end', function () {
    if (bytes !== bytesRecieved) reject('Error!');
});
...
```

Comment: That seems inefficient

Comment: Can you explain why it is more inefficient to compare the bytes received rather than comparing the bytes written? Do you mean inadequate instead? I could see how it might be possible to end up with a broken image if the stream fails in some way.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant inadequate. `bytesWritten` property is gonna get calculated anyways, and you are calculating it again performing a sum with the length of each chunk of data in your variable `bytesReceived`. On the other hand I don't see how the `writeStream` would not get `closed` if the download process starts. Can you explain the case to me?